# How to show a Modal once onShowMoreClick is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<OneProfileKeyCard
    title="Qualification"
    showMoreText="See all qualifications"
    onShowMoreClick={() => console.log('show more')}
>
    Creating, communicating, and implementing the organization&apos;s vision, mission, and overall direction Leading the development and implementation of the overall organization&apos;s strategy.
</OneProfileKeyCard>
```

```
import React from 'react'
import './OneProfileKeyCard.scss'

type Props = {
    title: string
    showMoreText: string
    onShowMoreClick: () => void
}

export const OneProfileKeyCard: React.FC<Props> = ({
    title,
    showMoreText,
    onShowMoreClick,
    children
}) => (
    <div className="one-profile-key-card">
        <h3>{ title }</h3>
        <div>
            { children }
        </div>
        <button type="button" onClick={onShowMoreClick}>
            { showMoreText }
        </button>
    </div>
)
```

could anyone help me to set up a modal? Im trying to set up a modal once onShowMoreClick is clicked that would turn the children(creating, communicating, and implementing the organization...) into a modal. So far it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have a state-managed in the parent component of where the `OneProfileKeyCard` child component is called from.

Something like this

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState(false)

return (
   <div>
       <h1>Demo</h1>
        <OneProfileKeyCard
            title="Qualification"
            showMoreText="See all qualifications"
            onShowMoreClick={() => setModalOpen(!modalOpen)}>
                text ... text
        </OneProfileKeyCard>
   </div>
   )
}
```

I'm not sure what else is within your components, but you'll then need a way to close the model, right now I have set the showMoreClick prop to open/close, but if that should open then set it to `true` and do a similar pass-through for a closing `false` function.

Comment: I did some extra research on setState and props but it was your response that tied it all together and helped me find the solution to this question. Thanks a lot for all your help!